# jQuery .fadeOut problems in FireFox 6.0

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseout, mouseleave

So far, I have the `fadeIn` working, but the `fadeOut` has not been quite right.  Right now, as soon as the mouse leaves the hover area, it doesn't look like any `fadeOut` is happening at all.  I would like to have a smooth fade out that completes before the next animation (the next `fadeIn`) begins and doesn't queue up.  Basically this is over some links that are within `<span>` tags.  I'm in the home stretch now!

P.S. I know I'm not using `.hover`.  I'd rather stick with `mouseover` and `mouseleave` for now, or even `mouseout`.  Please accomodate this small request.

```
<script>
    $("a").mouseover(function () { 
        $("div").fadeIn(0, function () { 
            $("span").fadeIn(3000,0.0);
        }); 
        return false; 
    });  

    $dequeue;

    $("a").mouseleave(function () { 
        $("span").fadeOut(3000,0.0);
    });
</script>


<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#">MouseOver!</a>

<div>

<h3><span>Sample Text</span></h3>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: 08/18/2011

I realized that there may be script conflicting with the one above.  I have an additional jquery script running on the same page.  By itself it works fine, but when I add the script for the text box (above) the .fadeOut on both images and text becomes ignored or at the very least, inconsistent.

2nd jQuery script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".latest_img").fadeTo("slow", 0.0);
$(".latest_img").hover(function(){
$(this).fadeTo(1000, 1.0).dequeue();

},function(){
$(this).fadeTo(1000, 0.0).dequeue();
});
});
</script>
```

Here is an example of one of the four "targets" that should prompt the text and image to display (there are four text boxes accompanying four images - each get shown by a mouseover on the target).

HTML:

```
<div class="gallerycontainer">
<div width="100%" height="30%">

<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><h2 class="ftb" id="tg1">Target A</h2>

<span class="txspan">
<img src="img/ima.jpg" class="latest_img" id="images" />
<h3 class="text"><br>Textbox content for Target A</h3></span></a>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is $dequeue; ? if its not defined you may be getting you js broken.

Comment: @Fresheyeball It's from here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.dequeue/ I think I'm using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

sans the `$dequeue` both events seem to be working

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/y9qd6/

```
$("a").mouseover(function() {
    $("div").fadeIn(0, function() {
        $("span").fadeIn(3000, 0.0);
    });
    return false;
});

// remove $dequeue

$("a").mouseleave(function() {
    $("span").fadeOut(3000, 0.0);
});
```

**EDIT:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/y9qd6/

```
var $a = $('a'),
    $div = $('div'),
    $span = $('span');

$a.mouseover(function() {
    $div.show();
    $span.fadeIn(1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $span.stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

this should work like you're looking for, the `span` fades out completely before fading back in.

Comment: Yeah.  It seems to work in my example, but it doesn't work on my page.  :(  The dequeue was supposed to take the animation out of the queue so that animations wouldn't stack up.  Since it doesn't work with that in or out for me, it dosn't yet solve my issue.

Comment: @Scott, you can [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the fade animation before calling the fade methods so they don't stack something like `$('span').stop(true, true).fadeIn(3000, 0.0);`

Comment: Won't the .stop abruptly stop the animation without letting it complete?  That's what seems to be happening with the fadeOut.

Comment: the example does stop any current animation abruptly, you have control over that though, you can call the `.stop([clearQueue], [jumpToEnd])` method using the arguments as you see fit, the defaults are `false`.  Sounds like you may want `.stop(true, false)`

Comment: When I add .stop() no animation at all occurrs.

Comment: There appear to be some conflicts in my script.  I've updated my question with (hopefully) the relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `dequeue`. Use `stop()` instead:

```
$("a").mouseover(function () { 
    $("div").fadeIn(0, function () { 
        $("span").fadeIn(3000,0.0);
    }); 
});  

// using ".stop()" will stop the previous animation, and immediatly fade it out

$("a").mouseleave(function () { 
    $("span").stop().fadeOut(3000,0.0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it hasn't fixed the issue.  I've tried a number of fixes including adding a background color and using fadeTo instead of fadeIn and fadeOut.  So far nothing's worked.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you try explaining it more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Place everyting inside the document ready event
2. Remove the $dequeue.
3. Add stop(true, true) before the fadeIn's and fadeOut's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").mouseover(function () { 
      $("div").stop(true, true).fadeIn(0, function () { 
          $("span").fadeIn(3000,0.0);
      }); 
      return false; 
  });  

  //$dequeue;

  $("a").mouseleave(function () { 
      $("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut(3000,0.0);
  });
});
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider using the mouseenter and mouseleave instead so that the event only fires once - when the cursor enters the anchor... and leaves it.

Comment: I have a prior jQuery statement above, though in separate SCRIPT tags.  When I use the document.ready statement this animation doesn't run, so I took it out.

Comment: Yes, am currently using mouseenter and mouseleave.  I must have pulled the example from a prior iteration.  Everything else is the same, though.

Comment: Try putting the document ready back again, with the corrected syntax. It should work. Also, are you intending the animation to actually play within 3 seconds? Seems slow... But that's just me. I'd rather pass 'fast' as a duration in the fadeIn and fadeOut animations.

Answer (score 0):

$dequeue is the wrong syntax. It needs to be $.dequeue and be passed an element ie $.dequeue(elem). Also you are not using a queue statment so dequeue is inappropriate. stop() would be wise on both fades. no need to pass any arguments to stop() default should work fine.